# Prove $\sqrt{n}$ to be non-Cauchy

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I’m trying to prove that the sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_n=\sqrt{n}$ is not a Cauchy sequence, but I’m quite unsure how to provide a counter example for a general chosen epsilon.

Comment: Does $a_{n+1} - a_n$ tend to $0$?

Comment: Hint: if a sequence is Cauchy, then is bounded.

Comment: To be honest, this is about as obviously not a cauchy sequence as they get.  It's not bounded, it doesn't converge, the difference in consecutive terms not only don't get closer together they get *further* apart.  We don't even need to get into the precise definition of Cauchy of all terms get closer together.  This fails from the get-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy.

Given $ \epsilon \gt 0$ there is a  $n_0$ such that

for $m,n \ge n_0 :$

$|a_m-a_n| \lt \epsilon.$

Choose $m= (k+n_0)^2$ , $n=n_0^2.$

$|a_m-a_n| = |k| \lt \epsilon.$

Choose $k \in \mathbb{Z+}$ such that $k > \epsilon.$
(Archimedes).

Hence not Cauchy.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint** Set $m=4n$

$$\left| \sqrt{4n}-\sqrt{n}\right|=\sqrt{n} $$
can be easily made larger than $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\varepsilon=1$. If $p\in\mathbb N$, then, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n=+\infty$, there is a $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $\sqrt m\geqslant\sqrt p +1$. Let $n=p$. Then $m,n\geqslant p$ and$$\left|\sqrt m-\sqrt n\right|\geqslant 1=\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{n} = \infty$

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overthinking this.  As the elements of $\{\sqrt{n}\}$ get *further* apart from each other as $n$ increase this is clearly *not* Cauchy.

Finding a counter example is simply a matter of finding $m > n$ so that $\sqrt{m} - \sqrt n > \epsilon$.  Or in other words $\sqrt{m} > \sqrt n + \epsilon$.  Or in other words $m > (\sqrt n + \epsilon)^2 = n + 2\sqrt{n}\epsilon + \epsilon^2$....

Well, that *IS* your counter-example.  For any $\epsilon > 0$ let and $M$ be any real value.  There will always be $n,m$ so that $M < n < n + 2\sqrt{n}*\epsilon + \epsilon^2 < m$ so that $|\sqrt{m} - \sqrt{n}| > \epsilon$.

====

And even *MORE* obvious.  In the reals all Cauchy sequence converge.  (That's pretty much the definition of the real numbers... more or less).  And clearly $\{\sqrt{n}\}$ do not converge.

Answer (score 1):

$b_n:=a_{n^2}$ is a subsequence which is clearly not Cauchy (it is $b_n=n$). Hence, $a_n$ can't be Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n=\sqrt{n}$ then
$$
|a_{2n^2}-a_{n^2}|=n\sqrt{2} \not\to 0 \,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\,\min(2n^2,n^2)=n^2 \to \infty.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $(u_n) $ is Cauchy then we will have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(u_{n^2}-u_n)=0$$
since $(u_{n^2}) $ is a subsequence of $(u_n) $.

but

$$u_{n^2}-u_n=\sqrt {n}(\sqrt {n}-1) $$
goes to $+\infty $.

thus $(u_n) $ is not Cauchy.